# Moving to second viewController after selecting an item in the rootController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I created app that have tableView with a viewController, what it should do is after selecting an item move to the second viewController and open it with passed data. I am implementing the next thing in the RootTableView:

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *selecteditem = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

DetailViewController *dvController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
dvController.selectedItem = selectedItem;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
[dvController release];
dvController = nil;

}
```

this code should work basicly but after I am selecting an item its been selected(blue colored) and that it, its stays with the selected blue color and nothing happened...after i selecting another row the same thing happens, what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to disable the selection styling when adding cells to your table:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

Answer (score 0):

just put following code into your code

```
  [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:
      [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];
```

like i.e

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *selecteditem = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
// implement my code
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];

DetailViewController *dvController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
dvController.selectedItem = selectedItem;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
[dvController release];
dvController = nil;

}
```

Comment: I am getting an error on this line : [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES]; saying "Incompatible pointer types sending 'UITableView*' to parameter of type \NSIndexPath*'

Comment: in place of the tableView put your UITableview object name like if you are creating the property name as tblData then put code like [self.tblData deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tblData indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];

Comment: the only correct syntax that worked was : [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES]; but it's doesn't worked...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the navigationController. It might be not initialized. 
You must have a UINavigationController to push any controller inside.

Comment: the viewcontroller you are using must be added to UINavigationController. Take a look at this http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/03/uinavigationcontroller-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks @Neal...but if i am not started from a new project, I have already working project and i want to add rootContreller and secondController. do i have to put the UinavigationController to the rootController or to the mainController of the project?

Comment: the first view that starts after calling the start page of views is declared like this :  `AppDelaget *appDelagate = (AppDelagate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];startPage *startPage = ]]StartPage alloc] initWithNibName:@"startP" bundle:nil]; [app delegate.viewcontroller presentModalViewController:startPage animated:YES];` Maybe something incorrect here?